# Creating unique braces below equations

Tags: equations, braces

I would like to create something like this[image: this].

Specifically my question is about how those curly braces below are drawn and labelled.

Comment: Have you considered the `\underbrace` macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

equation is not complete (since you not provide code mwe), but finish it should not be a problem to you

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\int\underbrace{\int_0^\pi \frac{2y}{R^2}\left( ... \sqrt{1-\frac{y}{4}}\right)dy}_{\mathcal{A}} dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Its very clear, thanks @Zarko! +1